# Firebase push gave me SyntaxError: invalid object initializer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari, firebase

so I am experiencing some very strange problem. I am trying to connect to my firebase and push results to 'surveyAnswers' and it does work in chrome ( ios ) but doesn't work on firefox/safari ( ios ).

Here is code which make problem - `surveyAnswers.push({answers});`

And here is 'complete' code:

```
    var surveyAnswers = new Firebase("https://#####.firebaseio.com/");

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        if(questionsAnswered<30){
            alert('Molimo Vas da odgovorite na sva pitanja iz ankete.');
        }else{
            surveyAnswers.push({
                answers
            });
            $(".message").fadeIn('fast');
            vaCenter(); 
        }            
    });
```

Please don't ask for more code because this is the part which makes me problem and rest of the code is huge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the intention of the braces surrounding `answers`? Remove them if there is none, or add a `{key_name: answers}` if that's what's required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid JavaScript:

```
surveyAnswers.push({
    answers
});
```

If you want to add the answers as part of an object, you'll need to give them a name:

```
surveyAnswers.push({
    answers: answers
});
```

If you just want to add `answers` as *the* object, do this:

```
surveyAnswers.push(answers);
```

So without the braces.

Answer (score 0):

use `.$add` insted of `.push`. 
hope it works.

Comment: `$add` is part of AngularFire's `$firebaseArray` class. `$add` is not available on the Firebase JavaScript SDK, since it's called `push` over there. :-)